# Erro na declaração de relacionamento 1 para 1 no EF com code-first e atributos!

Tags: c#, code-first, entity-framework-6, atributos

Tenho as seguintes classes em que quero fazer um relacionamento 1 para 1:

Usuário:

```cs
[Table("Usuario")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Index("unq_Usuario_Login", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Usuario")]
    public virtual UsuarioConfiguracao Configuracoes { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Usuario")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioDepartamento> Departamentos { get; set; }
}
```

Configurações do Usuário:

```cs
[Table("UsuarioConfiguracao")]
public class UsuarioConfiguracao
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioId")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool EMailDeAtendimento { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool EMailDeArquivoPublicado { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool SmsDeAtendimento { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool SmsDeArquivoPublicado { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Ao rodar o `enable-migrations` obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Dominio.Usuario' and 'Dominio.UsuarioConfiguracao'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations..

Creio que já vi questões semelhantes aqui no SOpt mas não encontrei.
**E gostaria de saber como resolver com os `Attributes` e porque isso ocorre?**

---

### Edição

Ao colocar o atributo `Required` na propriedade `Configuracoes` da classe `Usuario` meu erro mudou:

```cs
[Required]
[InverseProperty("Usuario")]
public virtual UsuarioConfiguracao Configuracoes { get; set; }
```

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Usuario' on type 'Dominio.UsuarioConfiguracao' is not valid. The foreign key name 'UsuarioId' was not found on the dependent type 'Dominio.Usuario'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Achei estranho mas mudei na minha classe UsuarioConfiguracao para:

```cs
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
```

**E funcionou a adição do *Migrations*. Isto está certo? Porque ele não aceitou o `UsuarioId`? Não deveria ser a propriedade da própria classe em que o atributo esta, que no caso faria referência à `Key` da classe que se faz a referência?**

Comment: Cara, acho que nao precisa declarar o UsuarioId duas vezes como você ta fazendo... Tira aquela anotação de ForeignKey de Usuario pra ver se funciona. Talvez seja isso.

Comment: Isso resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: Porque esse Id que você ta puxando como chave estrangeira é da sua tabela de Usuario e não da tabela UsuarioConfiguração, ou seja, o conceito de herança da resposta abaixo. Entendeu ?

Comment: Tranquilo cara. Precisando estamos ai !

Answer (score 4):

***1 para 1***

*Se você usar a regra de 1 para 1, no **EntityFramework** seria mais ou menos assim:*

```
[Table("Usuario")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Index("unq_Usuario_Login", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Usuario")]
    public virtual UsuarioConfiguracao Configuracoes { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Usuario")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioDepartamento> Departamentos { get; set; }
}


[Table("UsuarioConfiguracao")]
public class UsuarioConfiguracao: Usuario
{           
    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool EMailDeAtendimento { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool EMailDeArquivoPublicado { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool SmsDeAtendimento { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool SmsDeArquivoPublicado { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Ou seja, em termos gerais chama-se `Herança`

***Obs:*** *não conferi todo os seus campos, só coloquei a forma original de 1 para 1*

Comment: Claro que teria! é herdado da classe Usuario.

Comment: Isso... você vai ter que usar técnica com OfType e varias macetes para funcionar, eu já utilize em um projeto e ficou muito legal!!! fica bem organizado!